# R Leaflet throwing "matrix(): subscript out of bounds" with an addGeoRaster object

Tags: r, land-cover, stars, leaflet-r

I am trying to render a large GeoTIFF (meter-scale urban land cover or MULC from the EPA EnviroAtlas [found here](https://gaftp.epa.gov/epadatacommons/ORD/EnviroAtlas/MSPMN_MULC_tif.zip)) in Leaflet along with other spatial data. Because of the size (approx. 65k x 80k) I'm using a stars proxy and attempting to add to Leaflet using leafem::addGeoRaster().

I've tested my code with a demo GeoTIFF, and I'm able to render my MULC tiff using base plot(), but when I try to add it to leaflet I get the following error, and it's unclear where in the pipeline it's happening:

> Error in matrix(seq_len(prod(dims[dxy])), dims[dxy[1](https://gaftp.epa.gov/epadatacommons/ORD/EnviroAtlas/MSPMN_MULC_tif.zip)],
> dims[dxy[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBdWs.png)])[xy] :    subscript out of bounds

Test code and output below:

```
library(stars)
library(leaflet)
library(leafem)

tif = system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
r <- read_stars(tif, proxy = TRUE)
rasterio = list(nXOff = 6, nYOff = 6, nXSize = 100, nYSize = 100, bands = c(1,3,4))
(x = read_stars(tif, RasterIO = rasterio))
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addGeoRaster(x)

mulc_tif <- file.path("MSPMN_MULC_tif","MSPMN_MULC.tif")
rasterioMulc = list(nXOff = 21000, nYOff = 10000, nXSize = 100, nYSize = 100)
(mulc = read_stars(mulc_tif, RasterIO = rasterioMulc))
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addGeoRaster(mulc)

plot(mulc)
```

Output:

```
...
>(x = read_stars(tif, RasterIO = rasterio))
stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
             Min. 1st Qu. Median     Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
L7_ETMs.tif    23      54     63 62.05977   73.25  235
dimension(s):
     from  to  offset delta                     refsys point values x/y
x       6 105  288776  28.5 SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 25S FALSE   NULL [x]
y       6 105 9120761 -28.5 SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 25S FALSE   NULL [y]
band    1   3      NA    NA                         NA    NA   NULL  

...

>leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addGeoRaster(x)
```

[image]

```
>(mulc = read_stars(mulc_tif, RasterIO = rasterioMulc))
stars_proxy object with 1 attribute in 1 file(s):
$MSPMN_MULC.tif
[1] "[...]/MSPMN_MULC.tif"

dimension(s):
   from    to  offset delta                refsys point values x/y
x 21000 21099  438429     1 NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N FALSE   NULL [x]
y 10000 10099 5017332    -1 NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N FALSE   NULL [y] 

...

>leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addGeoRaster(mulc)
Error in matrix(seq_len(prod(dims[dxy])), dims[dxy[1]], dims[dxy[2]])[xy] : 
  subscript out of bounds

...
    
>plot(mulc)
```

[image]

At @Spacedman's request, here's the call stack:

```
> traceback()
4: transform_grid_grid(st_as_stars(src), st_dimensions(dest), threshold)
3: stars::st_warp(x, crs = 4326)
2: addGeoRaster(., mulc)
1: leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addGeoRaster(mulc)
```

It looks like the issue is specifically with st_warp, which throws the error even when passing the tiff's own CRS as destination:

```
> st_warp(mulc, crs = st_crs(mulc)
Error in matrix(seq_len(prod(dims[dxy])), dims[dxy[1]], dims[dxy[2]])[xy] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: It looks like a bug in st_warp where its trying to warp things that have been subsetted by passing a rasterIO parameter. Report to the stars issue tracker?

Comment: You'll probably struggle with this anyway - its a very large raster and having it on a leaflet map will still take loads of browser memory and loading time. Usual solution for large rasters is to convert to tiles at different resolutions.

Comment: I spend a good chunk of time on this yesterday and it looks like an issue under the hood when a default destination geometry is generated for a proxied tif, where lookup indices start at the subsetted values but the generated values start at 1. I'll open an issue.

Comment: And as it turns out, after all this I was also able to get what I need visualized by just passing a st_downsample() result to leaflet.